# Applying default serializer to properties in Custom Serializer (GSON)

Tags: java, json, gson

I am writing a custom serializer for my domain objects in GSON, so it only serializes certain objects:

```
 @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(BaseModel src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {

        JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();


        Class objClass= src.getClass();

        try {
            for(PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor : 
                Introspector.getBeanInfo(objClass, Object.class).getPropertyDescriptors()){

                                    if(BaseModel.class.isAssignableFrom(propertyDescriptor.getPropertyType()))
                {
                    //src.getId()
                }
                else if(Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(propertyDescriptor.getPropertyType()))
                {
                    //whatever
                }
                else {
                    String value = (propertyDescriptor.getReadMethod().invoke(src)) != null?propertyDescriptor.getReadMethod().invoke(src).toString():"";
                    obj.addProperty(propertyDescriptor.getName(), value);
                }
            }
        } catch (IntrospectionException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return obj;
    }
```

The thing is I also want to serialize HashMaps, but this way I get values like these:

{"key"=com.myproject.MyClass@28df0c98}

While I want the default serializing behavior Gson applies to HashMaps. How can I tell GSON to act "normally" with serializing certain objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**WARNING: Answer out of date.**
*Although this answer was initially accepted and upvoted, later on it's also had downvotes and comments saying it's wrong, so I guess it's out of date.*

---

I'm pretty sure you can use the `JsonSerializationContext context` object that you have as a parameter of the `serialize` method.

Actually, according to [Gson API documentation](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonSerializationContext.html), this object has a method serialize that:

> Invokes default serialization on the specified object.

So I guess you just need to do something like this in the point where you want to serialize your `HashMap` *normally*:

```
context.serialize(yourMap);
```

Comment: For me it will use the custom serialization and this will end up in an infinite loop...

Comment: The documentation of the function literally says not to do that: "Invokes default serialization on the specified object passing the specific type information. It should never be invoked on the element received as a parameter of the JsonSerializer.serialize(Object, Type, JsonSerializationContext) method. Doing so will result in an infinite loop since Gson will in-turn call the custom serializer again."

Answer (score 0):

What you COULD do is to instantiate another GsonBuilder and use that.
You can even append additional info, like I do in the last line of code (33% chance of being able to edit the list)

```
final GsonBuilder gb = new GsonBuilder();
JsonObject serializedObject = (JsonObject) gb.create().getAdapter(HashMap.class).toJsonTree(yourMap);
serializedObject.addProperty("canEdit", Math.random < 0.33); // append additional info
```

You can then include that serializedObject into your properties, or return it.